# RubyForge dead - now what?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize

Does anyone know what happened to RubyForge.org? The website is always down now. If it's permanently dead, does anyone know where they put all the stuff they used to host?

I end up using Ruby a couple times a year to do specific little projects and so I'm not up on what's going on in the gem world. I'm trying to find the documentation for the Mechanize Gem, which used to be hosted on Rubyforge and all the links I can find to it still point to Rubyforge. Anyone know where it might be?

Comment: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the mechanize doc here http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html (from https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) and here http://rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize,

About the documentation link from https://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize, it would be nice if you inform the maintainers via an issue on github.

**Update** mechanize doku link is updated, rubyforge officially dead.

Comment: OK, thanks! That helps immensely! I submitted an issue on github to let them know too.

Answer (score 0):

The [Seattle Ruby Brigade](http://www.seattlerb.org/) also maintains a lot of gems used in Rails and for other uses. Of course, you could figure out how to get there but just as an FYI for everyone who might just google search 'rubyforge' they have a nice site.

The [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) gem is now with sparklemotion.